# Laravel Model multiple versions

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am looking for a way how to return only the newest version of model for table and all other versions of model consisting of multiple unique columns.

```
$table->string('document_number');
$table->string('version');
$table->unique(['document_number','version']);
```

Example of showing only newest version:

```
ABCDoc1 Version 1
ABCDoc1 Version 2
ABCDoc2 Version 1
ABCDoc2 Version 2
ABCDoc2 Version 3
        
Desired Result:
ABCDoc1 Version 2
ABCDoc2 Version 3
```

Example of showing older versions

```
ABCDoc1 Version 1
ABCDoc1 Version 2
ABCDoc2 Version 1
ABCDoc2 Version 2
ABCDoc2 Version 3
    
Desired Result:
ABCDoc1 Version 1
ABCDoc2 Version 1
ABCDoc2 Version 2
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `max` of your modified string of `version` in your query and don't forget to add `groupBy()` for grouping the result by `document_number`, for example :

```
YourEloquent::select(DB::raw("
    document_number,
    max( SUBSTR(version, -1, LOCATE(' ', version)) ) as max_version"))
    ->groupBy('document_number')->get();
```

You will get the result something like this https://paiza.io/projects/-yZtaUKekoabUDfzLihQgw?language=mysql